# Moving/Copying file in Ubuntu One folders triggers re-upload

Tags: ubuntu-one

I've several large files stored in U1. When I move a file to another folder (which is also synced) it triggers a re-upload of the file. The same happens if I copy the file to another folder. Doesn't U1 use the hash to identify similar files and save bandwith?

Using U1 on Lucid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been fixed in the version shipped in Natty.
If you don't want to upgrade, you can use a cutting edge version of Ubuntu One by using the nighly PPA, although it does come with some risk of it breaking from time to time: https://launchpad.net/~ubuntuone/+archive/nightlies

Comment: I think I remember that I've read somewhere that improvements to U1 will be made available to all Ubuntu versions. Using the unstable nightlies is not really a sulution. I hope U1 will be updated more frequently on all active releases. I mean, if an U1 client proofs stable for several month on a new release it could be released for LTS users as well. I think that especially U1 evolves fast and improvements should be available to all Ubuntu users. U1 competes with other solutions like Dropbox & SpiderOak.